# Русская                     транскрибция

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, фонетика, транскрипция

Сомневаюсь в правильности своей транскрипции,объясните ,как правильно:
бубенчик- буб'Эн'чи'к(или буб'Эн'чи(э)'к),к бабушке-кбАбушк'ь (или кбАбушк'э).позже-пОжъ или пОж'э ,сжечь-ж'Эч' или жЭч'  ,зеленщик -з'эли(э)н'щИк или ударение другое

Comment: В слове "транскрипция" пишется буква П, хотя транскрибировать. Это отражение фонетического чередования согласных на письме в виде исключения.

Answer (score 1):

бубенчик- буб'Эн'ч'ик

к бабушке-гбАбушк'ь,

позже- пОж'ы(э)-зж внутри корня произносится как долгий мягкий согласный Ж( с чёрточкой вверху);е после ж произносится как Ы с призвуком Э

сжечь-двойной твёрдый Ж (с чёрточкой вверху)- жЭч'

зеленщик -з'ьли(э)н'ш'Ик .Щ-ш мягкий, долгий.

Answer (score 0):

> з'ьли(э)н'ш'Ик

Может быть, з'ь л' и н'щ'Ик :[И] без призвука Э?

Comment: Зеленщик - буква Е после мягкого согласного в первом предударном слоге читается как И с призвуком Э.